# Guidelines for mini-Markdown formatting of icon-, button-, and feature-names?

Tags: discussion, markdown, formatting

When discussing specific Web Apps (such as Facebook, for example), are there guidelines for how things like icon-, button-, and feature-names should be formatted using mini-Markdown?

Answer (score 6):

There are no specific guidelines as such, but I often edit out these things:

- Backticks for `highlighting` something - please don't do that & let's use backticks only for code.
- Excessive bold/italics, specially for things like: I **want** to do *this* but WHY isn't it ***Working***
- Needless to say ALL CAPS stuff gets removed out.
- I'm likely to convert "manual" list items into Markdown formatted ones. Example:

1) Point 1
2) Point 2
3) Point 3

These I change to

1. Point one.
2. Point two.

Makes it much easier on the eyes.

Comment: Backticks are also good (in my opinion) for things like filepaths and for URLs that you don't want to automatically turn into links.

Comment: Interested in hearing more opinions specifically about backticks (regarding which I already see first signs of possible disagreement).  In fact, some feedback that *I* received on my use of backticks was what prompted me to ask this question here on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here's what I try to adhere to:

- Italics when referring to UI elements

  > Press the *Upload* button to upload your image
  >   ([Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/59471/2)):
- Backticks for inline code
  ([Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40030/if-or-statements/40033#40033)):

  > `function abc();`
- Four-space indents for code blocks
  ([Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40067/how-do-i-mail-merge-from-google-spreadsheet-to-a-google-document/40076#40076)):

  > ```
  > function abc() {
  >    alert("Boo");
  > }
  > ```
- Backticks when refering to on-screen elements that are not GUI elements
  ([Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/59756/revisions)):

  > Select row `1`
- Backticks also for error messages
  ([Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/60127/3)):

  > `Error deleting your file`
- `<kbd>` to specify keys to press
  ([Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/60359/2)):

  > Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy
- Bold for general emphasis:

  > Do **not** do this unless you know what you're doing

Does this make some sense?